# dict is not callable when assigning variable to fuction call

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have just finished function that reads a text file and sets it to a dictionary to be used as part of a schedule in a simple clock application, The function schedule works fine on it's own in a seperate script and called using:

```
schedule = schedule()
print(schedule)
```

However when I call it in the same way within the application, I get a 'dict is not callable error', how come I can't call it in the same way within my application?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Full screen clock

import tkinter as tk
import time

def schedule():                 # this function
    flag = False
    schedule = dict()
    times = []
    days_of_the_week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
                        "Thursday", "Friday",
                        "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/schedule.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            s = line.strip()
            if s == '':
                continue
            elif s in days_of_the_week:
                day = s
                times.clear()
            else:
                times.append(s)
                schedule[day] = times[:]

    return schedule

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.configure(background='black')
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.configure(background='black')
frame.pack(expand=tk.TRUE)
schedule = schedule()                 # function is called here


clock_lt = tk.Label(frame,
                 font=('Serene MTC', 230),
                 fg='#FF8000',
                 bg='black')
clock_lt.pack()

date_etc = tk.Label(frame,
                 font=('Ariel', 50),
                 fg='#FF8000',
                 bg='black')
date_etc.pack()

date_iso = tk.Label(frame,
                 font=('Ariel', 50),
                 fg='#FF8000',
                 bg='black')
date_iso.pack()

running_time = tk.Label(frame,
                        justify=tk.LEFT,
                 font=('Ariel', 15),
                 fg='#CDAF90',
                 bg='black')
running_time.pack()


def tick():
    schedule = schedule()
    time1 = ''
    time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M')
    date_etc_txt = "%s" % (time.strftime('%A')).upper()
    date_iso_txt = time.strftime('%d-%B-%Y').upper()
    today = date_etc_txt.title()


    if time2 != time1:
        time1 = time2
        clock_lt.config(text=time2)
        date_etc.config(text=date_etc_txt)
        date_iso.config(text=date_iso_txt)
        running_time.config(text=day_schedule[today])

    clock_lt.after(20, tick)

tick()
root.mainloop()
```

I don't understand what is different here? unfortunately, I don't know if this code fully works now as I can't get past this error, but if you comment out the line:

```
schedule = schedule()
```

it works fine.

Here is the test data I'm using:

```
Friday
08:00 - 08:30   Morning briefing
09:15 - 10:30   Shakedown

Saturday
08:00 - 08:30   Morning briefing
09:00 - 10:00   Prep and Warm Up

Sunday 
08:00 - 08:30   Morning briefing
09:00 - 10:00   Prep and Warm Up
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `schedule` as a variable and a function.

Once you do that, schedule is no longer a function but a variable.

As a result the interpreter loses it's mind and tells you that you're trying to call a dict (which you think is a function), but you just reassigned it as a variable.

Consider using a different function name (maybe `scheduler()`)

Answer (score 2):

```
schedule = schedule()
```

overwrites the function `schedule` with whatever the original function returnes (a `dict` in your case). from now on `schedule` is a `dict` (and can no longer be called).

change the variable where you store the return value to something else; e.g.:

```
sched = schedule()
```

and make sure to use `sched` (which is a `dict`) and `schedule` (a function) correctly.

Comment: so I have renamed the variable name to day_schedule and I am getting the same results?Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fsclock.py", line 82, in <module>
    tick()
  File "./fsclock.py", line 65, in tick
    day_schedule = schedule()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: are you running this in IDLE (or a different IDE that keeps a running python interpreter?). you'd need to restart the interpreter in that case.

Comment: and the line `schedule = schedule()` appears twice in your code. the second time in the `tick()` function.

Comment: Thanks hiro protagonist, that was the problem, I was moving it about to see if it was a problem with where it was and forgot to delete it. It works now, thanks for all your help.